# What is LINQ equivalent of SQL’s "IN" keyword

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

How can I write below sql query in linq

```
select * from Product where ProductTypePartyID IN
(
    select Id from ProductTypeParty where PartyId = 34
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntactic variations aside, you can write it in practically the same way.

```
from p in ctx.Product
where (from ptp in ctx.ProductTypeParty
       where ptp.PartyId == 34
       select ptp.Id).Contains(p.ProductTypePartyID)
select p
```

I prefer using the existential quantifier, though:

```
from p in ctx.Product
where (from ptp in ctx.ProductTypeParty
       where ptp.PartyId == 34
       && ptp.Id == p.ProductTypePartyID).Any()
select p
```

I expect that this form will resolve to an `EXISTS (SELECT * ...)` in the generated SQL.

You'll want to profile both, in case there's a big difference in performance.

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct equivalent in LINQ. Instead you can use contains () or any
other trick to implement them. Here's an example that uses `Contains`:

```
String [] s = new String [5];
s [0] = "34";
s [1] = "12";
s [2] = "55";
s [3] = "4";
s [4] = "61";

var  result = from d in  context.TableName
              where s.Contains (d.fieldname)
              select d;
```

check this link for details: [in clause Linq](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.com/2011/09/in-clause-with-linq-to-sql.html)

```
int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };


var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;
```

Comment: How did this get up-votes? It assumes the OP wants to filter on multiple numbers, which isn't the case, and it uses strings where the problem clearly calls for dealing with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this

```
var partyProducts = from p in dbo.Product 
                    join pt in dbo.ProductTypeParty on p.ProductTypePartyID equal pt.PartyId 
                    where pt.PartyId = 34 
                    select p
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the Contains in a Where clause.

Something along these lines (untested):

```
var results = Product.Where(product => ProductTypeParty
                                            .Where(ptp => ptp.PartyId == 34)
                                            .Select(ptp => ptp.Id)
                                            .Contains(product.Id)
                           );
```