# Linq to SQL "IN" Clause not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL query as:

```
select a.id, a.lastName + ',' + a.firstName FullName 
from account a
where a.id in(
        select a.EH_PP_TE_TeacherAcctID 
        from EH_PP_TeacherEvaluations a
        inner join EH_PP_TeacherEvaluationStatusesRefTable b
            on a.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusIDEH = b.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID
        where b.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusValue = 1)
    and a.id = '57DB0B08-4C58-4301-AB92-090D4D9B7DA5'
```

I want to translate it in LINQ.

After reading following answer:

[What is LINQ equivalent of SQL’s "IN" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255205/what-is-linq-equivalent-of-sqls-in-keyword?answertab=active#tab-top)

I made query as:

```
List<Entity.Observations> outerList = new List<Entity.Observations>();
outerList = (
                from a in context.accounts
                where
                (
                        from c in context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluations
                        join b in context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluationStatusesRefTables on c.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusIDEH equals b.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID
                        where b.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusValue == 1
                ).Any()
                select new Entity.Observations
                {
                    EH_PP_TeacherAcctId = Convert.ToString(a.account.id)
                }
            ).ToList<Entity.Observations>();
```

But its giving me error as:

A body must end with select clause or group clause (at Any())

Please help me how can i improve this query???

I am new with Linq.

Comment: You need a select in the query inside the `where` clause. LINQ query syntax always needs a `select`.

Comment: `Any()` roughly translates to the `EXISTS` keyword in SQL. If you want `IN` you need to use `Contains()`.

Comment: @DanielKelley but they havent written select inside where over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255205/what-is-linq-equivalent-of-sqls-in-keyword?answertab=active#tab-top  hence i didnt done that

Comment: @BearGrylls Interesting. However, the message is clear. It's up to you if you want to try changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Each nested query needs to end with a select statement to get the results you're looking for.  Without select, nothing will get returned.

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation with the SQL would be something similar to this: (I'm not doing the inner join but you can figure it out pretty easily)

```
from a in context.Accounts
where a.Id == "57DB0B08-4C58-4301-AB92-090D4D9B7DA5" && 
   context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluations.Join(.......)
        .Any(tv=>tv.EH_PP_TE_TeacherAcctID == a.Id)

select new {Id = a.Id, FullName = a.lastName + "," + a.firstName}
```

Please do note that there should be better ways of doing the `IN` using relationships in LINQ.