# How to write this WHERE condition in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I write this `where` condition in Linq?

```
var result = from i in context.ItemsFullDetails where i.iditem in (1,2,3,4)
```

`where` condition includes a list of id's where which be compared with the `iditem` column.

I am getting an error if I write in the above way.

Comment: Why shouting? no need to use capital letters for title...

Comment: How to use lower case in typing...

Comment: ***WHAT*** error? Please post the complete and exact error message....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
//create filter list
int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// check your search item exists in the filter list
var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;
```

Reference:
[What is LINQ equivalent of SQL’s "IN" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255205/what-is-linq-equivalent-of-sql-s-in-keyword/8255291#8255291)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/*Hold here the items you want to filter by*/
var filterCriteria = new List(){1,2,3,4};
/*Get results as Ienumerable<int>*/
var result = context.ItemsFullDetails.Where(i => filterCriteria.Contains(i.iditem));
```

If you want to get results as list / array, you can use `result.ToList()` / `result.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. The first, as I see many people have suggested on this and similar posts, is to create a collection external from the LINQ query and use `Contains` against that:

```
int[] items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var result = from i in context.ItemsFullDetails where items.Contains(i.iditem)
```

But that said, if your example here is more or less what you're actually looking to do and you do have a constant set of possibilities, I'd be more tempted to write out the logic:

```
var result = from i in context.ItemsFullDetails where i.iditem == 1
                                                      || i.iditem == 2
                                                      || i.iditem == 3
                                                      || i.iditem == 4
```

Now, this is nearly as pretty. I agree. *But* this will be the most efficient way to do what you're after, and I don't think it's unreadable enough--particularly to experienced developers who are inherently used to logic like this--to warrant a lack of efficiency. Now, obviously, this approach only works if you have a compile-time collection set. But since you did in your example, I'm assuming you will in real life. So that's what I'd do. Then you don't have to risk looping through the entire collection for every element.

Or if you need a dynamic set of conditions:

```
List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

items.Add(...);;

var result = from i in context.ItemsFullDetails where items.Contains(i.iditem)
```

Comment: how the same can be done if we are using a variable which contains itemID's and if there are many more where conditions ?

Comment: @Sagar I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean. You could do `where items.Contains(i.iditem) && otherNumber == 12`, or that kind of thing. Is that what you mean?